# Jenkins - How to Get the Changes Set of an Upstream Build (in Groovy)

Tags: groovy, jenkins

In other words, I have project A that in Jenkins has a trigger on "Build after other projects are built" for projects B and C.

I'm sending a post-build notification email for project A and I'd like to include the changes set of B or C that triggered the build.

I looked at the Jenkins API docs and there is a getUpstreamBuilds() but when I try it I get an empty list. Any suggestions?

Thanks